# how can I monitor sandboxed PayPal NVP service calls in developer portal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I see in executing the ruby sample from the [github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby/blob/master/README.md](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby/blob/master/README.md) that tests against the App ID APP-80W284485P519543T will succeed, no matter what credentials are configured.

Moreover, I gather from the 'FOR APP TESTING' message at the bottom of the welcome page to the Adaptive Payments Developer Apps portal, [www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications](http://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications), that it is not possible to set up a PayPal NVP test account with dummy user accounts:

[image: pic of www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications]

Does this mean, then, that transactions from sandboxed use of PayPal NVP services cannot be configured to show at [developer.paypal.com/developer/dashboard/sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/dashboard/sandbox/)?

Answer (score 0):

In developer.paypal.com dashboard => Sandbox=>Transactions, it only list REST API transactions. There is no place to show NPV service API calls in developer website. you need to login sandbox.paypal.com to check the transaction list.